# how is a sheet name referenced in google app script macro?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google app scripts, I want a macro to copy data from one sheet (‘source’) to another sheet (‘dest1’).
I want to name the sheets in the macro.

```
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('source');
var dest1 = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('dest1');

function copy_source_to_dest1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:E70').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('dest1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('source!A1:E70').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
};
```

Comment: Do you mean *to rename*? `dest1.setName('new_name')` probably? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setName(String)

Comment: Thank you, Yuri, I used the solution below from pgSystemTester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having a hard time using your two variables? If so... you might consider this modified code. If you want rename a sheet, I included an example of that also. [Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a68KyzLm8J4UYXkbES6i7gn6vb97-Fbx24V3dAp7A8g/edit?usp=sharing) to illustrate result.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function copy_source_to_dest1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const source = ss.getSheetByName('source');
  const dest1 = ss.getSheetByName('dest1');
  const pullRange = source.getRange('A1:E70');

  //pickyour copy paste type by removing slashes to uncomment them.
  //pullRange.copyTo(dest1.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  //pullRange.copyTo(dest1.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  //pullRange.copyTo(dest1.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);


  //example of renaming a sheet?
  //dest1.setName("newName")
}
```

Comment: psSystemTester, thank you. I tried your answer function, but no data goes into sheet 'dest1'.  Your Test Sheet shows no data in sheet 'dest1' too.

Comment: Uhh. yea.... that's because you have it set to `Paste_FORMAT` in your original code.  What were you trying to do? I'll update my answer with a couple other options such as paste formula, values. Assuming that works, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, that did it, thank you. I got what you said and now my knowledge is better, again, thanks.

Comment: @MikeT Awesome. Glad it worked. Good luck.